# Nested 'Where'?

Tags: sql

I have a `table` named `Actor`, with only a column for `City` (CityId).  I want to return the number of actors in a particular `State` (StateId).  The catch however is that I have separate tables for `City`, `County`, and finally `State` (City has CountyId, County has StateId).  How do I this in a T-SQL query?

I have a solution that involves nested Select statements, something like:

```
  SELECT COUNT(1) 
     FROM Actor a 
     WHERE a.CityId IN 
           (SELECT CityId FROM City WHERE CountyId IN...)
```

...but is there a more efficient way to do this?  Thanks

Comment: pls put some sample of your table and required result

Comment: You can use JOINS to make this work, that would be an efficient way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  You can use this query to get your output
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    SELECT COUNT(ActorId)
FROM Actor a
INNER JOIN City c ON a.cityId = c.cityId
INNER JOIN Country con ON c.countryId = con.countryId
INNER JOIN STATE s ON con.stateId = s.stateId
GROUP BY s.stateId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JOINS to query your data.
I am using INNER JOIN here.
Assuming that you have CountryId in your City Table, You can do it following way.
In case you don't have countryId in your City Table you have to apply one more INNER JOIN on State Table.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Actor a INNER JOIN
City b ON a.CityId = b.CityId 
WHERE b.CountryId IN (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily put the `JOINS` across different table that you have and then use the `Group By` clause to find out the total number of actors from specific `state`.

I have used the column name on the basis of my wild guess, you can change them with the original name that you have in your database.

```
SELECT StateId,
       Count(ActorId) AS Total
FROM ACTOR
INNER JOIN City ON Actor.CityId = City.CityId
INNER JOIN County ON County.CountyId = City.CountyId
INNER JOIN State ON State.StateId = County.StateId
GROUP BY State.StateId
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relation names, you can do something like this with joins:

```
select s.ID, s.Name, count(*)
from Actors a 
  inner join Cities c on c.ID = a.CityID
  inner join County cn on cn.ID = c.CountyID
  inner join State s on s.ID = cn.StateID
group by s.ID, s.Name
```

If you only need the `StateId` you don't even need to join with states, this will do:

```
select cn.StateID, count(*)
from Actors a 
  inner join Cities c on c.ID = a.CityID
  inner join County cn on cn.ID = c.CountyID
group by cn.StateID
```